# Why ItemSource gets reloaded when application culture gets changed?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, localization, cultureinfo

I have DataGrid Control with binded ItemSource to employees BindingList. When I change application's culture then, why it reloads all the data???

Here is my DataGrid :

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding Salary}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="en-US" Name="btnEn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnEn_Click"/>
    <Button Content="ja-JP" Name="btnJP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnJP_Click"/>
```

Employee class :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

BindingList :

```
    private BindingList<Employee> _employees;

    public BindingList<Employee> Employees
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_employees == null)
                _employees = new BindingList<Employee>();
            return _employees; 
        }
        set { _employees = value; }
    }
```

Culture Changing code on button's :

```
    private void btnEn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo CustomCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        CustomCulture.DateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat; // Change DateTimeFormat to make date always in en-US Culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CustomCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CustomCulture;
        this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-US");
    }

    private void btnJP_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo CustomCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
        CustomCulture.DateTimeFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat; // Change DateTimeFormat to make date always in en-US Culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CustomCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CustomCulture;
        this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("ja-JP");
    }
```

Any help is appriciated.

**UPDATE**

How can I stop this behaviour?? I don't want to reload whole data again on culture changing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occur's on language switching, tab switching and also on applying different theme. I tried googling to this issue & I found one solution.

Only way to get rid of this issue is to give fixed **ConverterCulture=en-US(Or your default Culture)** to binding.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language affects the UI; more specially the Measure, which requires a layout update.  This should be expected since changing the culture can mean the UI needs to read right to left, or a different cultures character set requires more or less room to display correctly.

You can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs.html#4e7eeffcf8617391) that `this.Language` is directly effecting the `Window` which inherits `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't get rid of the behavior.  Since it affects the UI, all parent controls will perform another layout pass if the layout was changed/affected.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414083/affectsmeasure-or-affectsarrange) for more details.

Comment: It is good behavior.  If everything in the DataGrid has a localized string, the localized version of the string will be retrieved and used in the updated layout pass.  It is the same concept of changing the culture of a Windows Operating system, apply a certain culture could require Windows to restart so it can correctly adjust to the changes.  You won't be able to work around changing the Thread's current culture.  You should research a different way to implement localization, require application restart, or deal with the refresh if you plan on proceeding.

Comment: Hey @NETscape  I found one solution to this issue... If I give fixed ConverterCulture to binding of DataGrid's ItemSource, then issue get's resolved. Debugger will only gets ItemSource on Start time... I will now answer to this que... Thank's.