# WPF custom control: When to use AffectsArrange, AffectsParentMeasure and AffectsParentArrange?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, rendering, custom-controls

Suppose there is a WPF custom control (based on the `Control` class) serving as a wrapper around an internal control. The wrapper overrides `MeasureOverride` as follows (`ArrangeOverride` is not overridden):

```cs
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
  myInternalControl.Width = getWidthBasedOnMyDependencyProperty();
  return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
}
```

The value returned by `getWidthBasedOnMyDependencyProperty()` depends on a certain `DependencyProperty`.

It is not apparent to me which `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions` besides `AffectsRender` and `AffectsMeasure` should be used when registering this `DependencyProperty`:

1. Is `AffectsArrange` necessary? After reading [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414083/affectsmeasure-or-affectsarrange) my understanding is that `AffectsArrange` is never necessary when `AffectsMeasure` is set. Is this correct?
2. What about `AffectsParentMeasure` and `AffectsParentArrange` in the described cenario? Can this `MeasureOverride` code affect a potential parent control?

Comment: When a value change of your dependency property shall trigger a MeasureOverride call, it should be sufficient to set `AffectsMeasure`, nothing else. A measure pass is automatically followed by an arrange pass, so setting `AffectsArrange` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Clemens: What about `AffectsParentMeasure`? When changing the value of the `DependencyProperty` changes the width of the internal control, then the `DesiredSize` of the custom control is changing, too. This seems to imply that the custom control's parent control should also be notified that it needs to recalculate its layout.

Comment: My understanding was that the dependency property is a property of the custom control, not of the "internal" control (note the `My` in `getWidthBasedOnMyDependencyProperty`). If it is a property of the internal control, and the internal control is a direct visual child of the custom control, you may use AffectsParentMeasure instead of AffectsMeasure.

Comment: @Clemens: The dependency property was indeed ment to be a property of the custom control. But changing it would not only change the `DesiredSize` of the internal control but (indirectly) also the `DesiredSize` of this custom control. My understanding is that in such a case a container control that holds my custom control needs to be notified about the change. Therefore I conclude that `AffectsParentMeasure` must be set on the custom controls dependecy property to accomplish such a notification. If you think this is not necessary, could you please explain what mechanism cares for it instead.

Comment: You can easily try is yourself. When you set AffectsMeasure, a new layout will be made on your custom control whenever the dependency property changes. This will automatically result in a new layout of its parent control. If you want to dig into the details of how this is implemented in the framework, you may take a look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: @Clemens: Just to recapitulate and making sure that I did understand you correctly: When setting `MeassureArrange` it is never (and not only in the use case I described) necessary to set `AffectsArrange`, `AffectsParentMeasure` or `AffectsParentArrange`. Correct?

Comment: Never say never. But in your case it seems to be sufficient. However, you could always just *try it out*:

Comment: I am never satisfied just with trail and error. Of course sometimes one has to give up to find an answer, if the opportunity cost seems too high. But especially in the case of a custom control, that is meant to be reused in arbitrary contexts, it would be good to reach a deeper understanding. It is a strange thing that even the WPF books do not seem to care very much about it.