# Screenshot of a not displayed page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

I am trying to make screenshots from all pages in my WPF app automatically, but i don't want to open all the pages and capture the screen when the content is loaded into the mainwindow. I would like to capture my page without displaying it. Is there a way?

Using the code below I get an emty image, if I pass a not displayed page. If I pass the mainwindow it works fine...

```
 public void CaptureScreen(UIElement source, Uri destination)
        {
            try
            {
                double Height, renderHeight, Width, renderWidth;

                Height = renderHeight = 500;//source.RenderSize.Height;
                Width = renderWidth = 500;// source.RenderSize.Width;

                //Specification for target bitmap like width/height pixel etc.
                RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new
                RenderTargetBitmap((int)renderWidth, (int)renderHeight, 96, 96,
                PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                //creates Visual Brush of UIElement
                VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(source);

                DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                using (DrawingContext drawingContext =
                drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
                {
                    //draws image of element
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new
                    Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(Width, Height)));
                }
                //renders image
                renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);

                //PNG encoder for creating PNG file
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
                using (FileStream stream = new
                FileStream(destination.LocalPath, FileMode.Create,
                FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Page needs an initial layout. Call Measure and Arrange, and perhaps also [UpdateLayout or InvalidateVisual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14414688/1136211).